# Xpages Application Layout SearchBar

Tags: xpages

I use the bootstrap and Application layout. I need to put all values(in array) from sesscionScope to SearchBar of Application Layout.I tried all the way i know and found on google. I couldn't be succeded. Do you have an idea How i can do this?

[SearchBar Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwyBL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to display sessionScope variables on a page and it's definitely possible to show links in the search bar. It's also possible to use the SearchBar facet (the screenshot does not imply you're attempting that).

Steps on how to do this:

1. Apply bootstrap theme to a copy of Ext Lib Demo database. I'd recommend this as best practice to have a benchmark for bootstrap. You should see the same links in the bootstrap search bar that you do in the Ext Lib OneUI search bar.
2. Try to display the sessionScope content in a Computed Text somewhere on a page. This will troubleshoot your code.
3. After setting the variable, if it doesn't show, refresh the page. If it then shows, you're not refreshing the right area.
4. Get familiar with the relevant nodes you want to use for displaying basic content. Ensure you can get static text showing, then apply the code to calculated the sessionScope variable.
5. You may need to concatenate the array into a single text string to display in a node: it's a node, not a repeat.
6. SessionScope variables are not in a view or folder, so View or Folder List (if you're trying to use that) won't work.

Without a more targeted question, I don't know where you're going wrong, so I can't be more specific than suggest methods to break down what you're doing to basics, to enable you to try to work out which bit is failing.

Bear in mind if you try to use the searchBar facet, you will probably not be able to just add a control there, you'll need to add a container control (e.g. Panel) and then put the other controls within it.

Beyond that, look at something like XPages Debug Toolbar for how that retrieves and displays sessionScope variables.

Answer (score 0):

i create a function and call it beforePageLoad Event. 
I put all search Criteries into this function then i call it in searchBar,
at the end It worked for me :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnWTH.png)